# Passing data buffers from C++ to LabVIEW

Tags: c++, labview

I am trying to create a LabVIEW DLL and call it from a C++ program but I am facing a problem of data passing.

A scientific camera I recently bought comes with a LabVIEW SDK, and nothing else. The example program provided with the SDK is mainly a while loop around two functions, ReadData and DecodeData.

- ReadData collects data from USB (using VISA read), the data obtained in one call contains several complete data blocks and an incomplete incoming block.
- DecodeData is called multiple times to process all the complete blocks (it removes the processed data from the buffer). When all the complete blocks have been processed, the remaining data (the beginning of the incoming block) is passed to ReadData which will concatenate its new data at the end of the buffer.

Full example code:
[image: Full example code]

Details of ReadData:
[image]

Details of DecodeData:
[image]

In the example program, written in LabVIEW, everything works fine. The problem is when I export these functions in a DLL. The memory buffers, inputs and outputs of both functions, are char arrays. After ReadData, my C++ program correctly obtains a buffer containg data, including null bytes.

The problem is when I inject this buffer in DecodeData, it seems that LabVIEW only takes into account the bytes before the first null byte... I guess that the char[] input is just processed as a null-terminated string and the rest of the data is just discarded.

I tried to add data converters ("string to byte array" at outputs and "byte array to string" at inputs) but the conversion function also discards the data after the first null character.

I could modify the .vi from the sdk to only handle byte arrays and not strings, but it uses lots of character processing functions and I would prefer leaving it as is.

How can I pass the data buffer from C++ to the LabVIEW DLL without losing part of my data?

Edit: here is the C++ code.

The header exported with the LabVIEW DLL:

```
int32_t __cdecl CORE_S_Read_data_from_USB(char VISARefIn[], 
    Enum1 blockToProcessPrevCycle, uint32_t bytesToProcessPrevCycle, 
    uint8_t inBytesRead[], uint32_t *BytesReceived, LVBoolean *DataReception, 
    uint8_t outBytesRead[], Enum1 *blockToProcess, uint32_t *bytesToProcess, 
    int32_t longueur, int32_t longueur2);

void __cdecl CORE_S_Decode_data(uint8_t inBytesRead[], 
    LVBoolean LUXELL256TypeB, uint32_t bytesToProcess, Enum1 blockToProcess, 
    Cluster2 *PrevHeader, LVBoolean *FrameCompleto, 
    uint32_t *bytesToProcessNextCycle, Enum1 *blockToProcessNextCycle, 
    Cluster2 *HeaderOut, uint8_t outBytesRead[], Int16Array *InfraredImage, 
    Cluster2 *Header, int32_t longueur, int32_t longueur2, int32_t longueur3);
```

Usage in my C++ source:

```
while (...)
{
    // Append new data in uiBytesRead
    ret = CORE_S_Read_data_from_USB(VISARef, blockToProcess, bytesToProcess, uiBytesRead, &BytesReceived,
        &DataReception, uiBytesRead, &blockToProcess, &bytesToProcess, BUFFER_SIZE, BUFFER_SIZE);

    if (DataReception == 0)
        continue;

    bool FrameCompleto = true;
    while (FrameCompleto)
    {
        // Removes one frame of uiBytesRead per call
        CORE_S_Decode_data(uiBytesRead, LUXELL256TypeB, 0, blockToProcess, &Header, &FrameCompleto,  &bytesToProcess, &blockToProcess, &Header,
            uiBytesRead, &InfraredImage, &Header, BUFFER_SIZE, BUFFER_SIZE, BUFFER_SIZE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @JanSchultke I added screenshots, is it enough?

Comment: It's difficult to say what is the problem with such few information.
I would use a reliable binary serialization/deserialization library like ProtoBuffer or FlatBuffer ( first is easier, second is faster and aimed to realtime data transfer).

Also, do not trust char*. Strings in C/C++ are meant to terminate on the first null byte. Use uint8* so, at least, if you call with it a string function you will get some compiler error/warning.

Same issues for C++ streams. Never trust stringstream for binary data, they are very misleading.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I do not process in any way the buffers in C++, I just get the pointer from readData and pass it to decodeData. I'll try adding uint8 converters in the LabVIEW modules.

Comment: Another approach would be using Kaitai and try to rewrite the same grammar.
Kaitai is a toolkit for creating parsers for binary data, it uses Yaml for designing the grammar and it can produce parsers for a lot of different languages.

Comment: I'd prefer not to modify too much the SDK, if possible.
The issue with using uint8 conversion is that the "uint8 array to string" LabVIEW converter seems to discard part of the data (after the first \0)... But maybe I miss something with these converters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little tricky to answer in this specific case but assuming that the problem is that NULL values in the buffer data are causing issues then it might be worth looking at the option to use *String Handle Pointers* for the String-Type controls and indicators of the VIs you are exporting.

This option can be selected during the "Define VI Prototype" stage of configuring the DLL Build

[image]

LabVIEW manages String Types internally as an integer of the string's length and an unsigned char array so it shouldn't matter what characters are used. For interfacing with external code, LabVIEW's `extcode.h` header defines an `LStrHandle` as follows:

```cpp
typedef struct {
    int32   cnt;        /* number of bytes that follow */
    uChar   str[1];     /* cnt bytes */
} LStr, *LStrPtr, **LStrHandle;
```

So a String Handle Pointer is of type `*LStrHandle`.

`extcode.h` provides the macros `LHStrBuf(LStrHandle)` and `LHStrLen(LStrHandle)` which can ease dereferencing for the String Handle Pointer when you want to read or update the string content and length. Also, note a NULL handle can be used to represent an empty string so don't assume that the handle will be valid without checking.

When creating or resizing String Handle Pointers to pass to a function, it is worth noting that an `LStr` has exactly the same in-memory representation as a LabVIEW-array so the function [`NumericArrayResize`](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvexcode/numericarrayresize/) with `typeCode` `uB` can create/resize a large enough buffer to store the string and the length-integer.

An example of creating a new String Handle Pointer for a string of length `required_string_length` is achieved by passing `NumericArrayResize` a handle pointer where the handle is NULL.

```cpp
LStrHandle* new_string_handle_pointer;
// assign NULL value to handle
*new_string_handle_pointer=0;
err = NumericArrayResize(uB, 1, (UHandle *)new_string_handle_pointer, required_string_length);
// new_string_handle_pointer will now reference the new LStrHandle
```

When updating the String value in a String Handle remember to write the string's characters to the uChar array **and** to update the size integer. From a performance view, it might not be worth shrinking a String Handle when updating it to a shorter string but you will need to resize it if you know the string you are writing to it will be longer than what it can hold.

You should clean up any handle that is passed to you from LabVIEW or a LabVIEW-based DLL so once you have finished with it, call [`DSDisposeHandle`](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvexcode/azdisposehandle_dsdisposehandle/) on the handle that the handle-pointer references.

For more information on LabVIEW's memory manager function please read [this guide](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvexcodeconcepts/memory_manager/).

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks for this detailed answer.